# SQL Server Powershell Error

Tags: powershell

Morning,

I have a small error with a Powershell Script I'm running on one of my servers.

Due to the nature in which SQL Server Reporting Services works on the later SSRS I have a powershell script that recycles the app pool and then uses DownloadString to get the URL to a string and force the pre-cache of the page.

Originally I had this script running locally on the SQL Server itself but I have moved it off that server, I am now receiving the following error:

> Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.". The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

The script looks like this

```
Stop-Service "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)"
Start-Service "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)"
$wc = New-Object system.net.webClient
$cred = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$wc.Credentials = $cred
$wc.DownloadString("http://server/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx")
```

Anybody able to point me in the right direction.

Cheers.

Comment: check in event log what was this error.

Comment: The web server responded that it encountered an internal error, so you need to check the web server logs.

Comment: any final solution about ?

Comment: The reason mine was not working was I needed to enable Powershell Scripts on the new server. This had slipped my mind as it was a long time ago that I did this.